# Getting deleted profile data reassociated

Tags: discussion, support

Can deleted profile data be re - associated with a new account if say maybe, at a later date a user decides to come back ? Is there any timeframe before this gets irrecoverably wiped ?

An example being someone creates an SO account at work and the primary mail address ( work domain ) gets deleted by the company ( or he just loses access ), a few months later he decides to come back and claim the User ID with a different account.

EDIT

This looks like its possible based on what MichaelT shared. Importantly its possible to get back only selective sites/data reassociated as well. Wondering if there is any specific criteria that staff follow in accepting / rejecting such requests ?

Comment: If you lose access, contact the team. If you have your account deleted, I wouldn't bother

Comment: Thanks @Bart .. I meant deleted and maybe created another new account but wants the old data to be associated with the new one.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Connecting to your deleted accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137675/213963)

Comment: @MichaelT : Thanks for sharing .. your link seems to suggest that it may be possible after all. Just that someone from the SE Team must be willing to help ..